# How do I fetch the current Y cursor in jsPDF autotable?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

My code:

```
if(table!=null){
   if(table.rows.length>1){ 
      doc.autoTable({  
         html: '#news_pos_details',  
         startX: 50, 
         startY: 144, 
         theme: 'grid',  
         columnStyles: {  
                 0: {  
                         cellWidth: 70,  
                 },  
                 1: {  
                         cellWidth: 70,  
                 },  
                 2: {  
                         cellWidth: 40, 
                 },
         },
         styles: {  
               fontSize: 15,
               cellWidth: 'wrap' 
         }  
     })
  }
  else{
      doc.setFontType("italic");
      doc.text(52,174,"No news available in this section");
  }
}

doc.text(//How do I know where to start text??)
```

I want to write some text below the table, but I am confused as to what the Y coordinate should be. It will be dynamic depending on the height of the table? So what's the workaround for it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> doc.lastAutoTable.finalY

```
doc.text("En votre aimable règlement", 20, doc.lastAutoTable.finalY + 46);
```